# Parsing Dates with PHP

Tags: php, parsing

i am trying to write a program but i have no idea what to with parsing a date in this format into into a date stamp

Jan 15 2005 12:00AM

i do not care about the 12:00AM as all the records have that 12:00AM appended to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the strtotime() function ... e.g.:
$new_date = strtotime("Jan 15 2005 12:00AM");

Answer (score 6):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert the date to unix timestamp. You can also use this timestamp with [date()](http://php.net/date) function to format it in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

A newer way to do this as of PHP 5.2 is to use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$datetime = new DateTime("Jan 15 2005 12:00AM");
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jnEZuD)